# Session invalidate on browser close not on page page refresh

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring-mvc, spring-security

I want to invalidate session on browser close.
I am using beforeunload, but this event is calling for all the anchor,form submit ,page refresh.

Please can somebody tell how to call beforeunload only for browser/tab close either by close button or by key boared(like ctrl+w),that should work for all browsers.

Comment: I used cookie logic . check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18670598/differentiate-browser-tab-close-and-refresh-to-detect-multiple-instances-of-app

Comment: here's a solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291553/is-there-a-way-in-javascript-to-detect-if-the-unload-event-is-caused-via-a-refre

Comment: Hi both solutions are not meeting my requirement,please can give valid solutions based on above criteria.

Comment: Hi please update solutions