# Call Page Method on Browser Close

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I need to call a pagemethod when the user closes the browser or active tabs of a particular ASP.NET 4.5.1 website, tried onbeforeunload, it is working sometimes but not consistent. Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: But i think onbeforeunload event fires even if you click the browser's back button. right?

Comment: @SankarRaj True. Even on page refresh too. :)

Answer (score 3):

Dealt with this problem long back.

- Sent a form request initially, failed to achieve. Worked 100/1 time.
- Sent a AJAX request. Yup. Good for few times. Again the issue in
  hands.
- Stopped trusting in browser request and implemented server side
  inactive methods.
- If no request raised from client for `x` sec/minutes, closed his
  session (managed with `sessiontimeout`, `cookies`).
- That's 100% guaranteed and no browser dependencies.

> Problems faced with browser trust.

- God knows why sometimes it works.
- Programmers cry when browser    crash
- No body knows when CPU shuts down and what happened to my
  browser close  request
- And many more natural disasters like this ....

Comment: +IE, most strange browser

Comment: @evc Universal truth :)

Comment: @Suresh,how can u be sure that user has closed the tab?user might be inactive for `x` seconds right?

Comment: @shreesha That is what, we don't exactly know when user closed the tab.  We can't depend on client. What we did in our case is, If user is inactive for x seconds, and comeback to do something after `x` seconds, we forced him to login again.

Comment: @Suresh, If we can not trust browsers then that is the only way left i think..thanks

Comment: @shreesha Hmm.. yes. Not much with remaining browser functionalities. Especially with [this browser close](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14898144/gwt-windowclosinghandler-firing-on-browser-refresh-too) and  [browser refresh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18670598/differentiate-browser-tab-close-and-refresh-to-detect-multiple-instances-of-app) evil issues.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the request a synchronous AJAX (pretty much the only circumstance in which synchronous AJAX is appropriately used); otherwise, it is a race whether the window will die before it manages to send a request or not.

Comment: Even Ajax call have n-number of fail cases.